# Hang Bathroom Light Fixture

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture

I've hung multiple lighting options before, but they have always been when there is a electrical box in the wall behind the drywall.  In this case, I removed the old light fixture in my bathroom, and there was a circular hole in the wall with wires hanging out of the wall.

Since there is no electrical box for me to screw the mounting bracket into, what is the proper way for me to hang the light fixture?

Comment: Many bathroom fixtures have integral junction boxes, negating the need for an in-wall box. Does yours?

Comment: Or this? [Bathroom vanity light with no junction box](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/119964/bathroom-vanity-light-with-no-junction-box)

Comment: Or this? [Old Work Box for Vanity Light?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/154803/old-work-box-for-vanity-light)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it right, you will need to install a round junction box and mount it securely and route the wires through it. Then attach your fixture to the box.

You can use one like this if there's a stud by the hole.

[image]

or this if there's no stud where the hole is.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need an "old work light box" (example pictured).

[image: old work light box]

In case you're not familiar with "old work" vs "new work" - old work is for retrofits where the walls are already finished. New work is used for new construction where they can install before the drywall & paint is applied.

Light boxes are what should have been installed here. If your round hole is very small you might need to embiggen it to the size that will fit a light box, and if it's very much larger than the box you might need to cut the drywall and replace a section of it - if you do that, you might as well install a New Work light box since you'll have the drywall off anyway.